# GregorianCalendar and DateFormat Java

Tags: java, date-format, gregorian-calendar

I am trying to do a simple exercise where I take a date, add 90 days to it, and format it to something like this:

> Monday, April 20, 1998.

I am to do this using `GregorianCalendar` and `DateFormat`. So far, I have this compiling code, but I get a runtime error where I cannot format the given `Object` as `Date`:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

class Assignment21 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        GregorianCalendar ddate = new GregorianCalendar(1994, 10, 20);
        ddate.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 90);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MM dd, yyyy");
        String date = sdf.format(ddate);
    }
}
```

How can I correctly output the predefined `GregorianCalendar` date using `DateFormat`?

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat` doesn't have a `format`  method taking a `Calendar` parameter .

Comment: Will I have to use DateFormat?

Comment: Just 3 little details: 1- in `Calendar` API, months are zero-indexed (January is `0`), so month 10 is actually November (not sure if you're aware, but anyway it's something to take care). 2- To get exactly the format `Monday, April 20, 1998`, you should use `new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy", Locale.US)` - the `java.util.Locale` specifies the language (if you don't set it, it'll use the JVM default, and it's not guaranteed to always be English). 3- Prefer to use - if possible - the new java.time API, explained in [@Basil Bourque's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46408956/7605325).

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to correct your code:

instead of

```
String date = sdf.format(ddate);
```

try:

```
String date = sdf.format(ddate.getTime());
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Such a simple thing I missed.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.of( 1994 , Month.OCTOBER , 20 )                  // Generate a date-only value, a `LocalDate` object, without time-of-day and without time zone.
.plusDays( 90 )                                            // Add a span of time. Using immutable objects, a new `LocalDate` object is instantiated, without altering the first.
.format(                                                   
    DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.FULL )
                     .withLocale( Locale.US )
)
```

> Wednesday, January 18, 1995

## java.time

You are using troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the *java.time* classes.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1994 , 10 , 20 ) ; // Sane numbering for year and month, unlike legacy classes. '1994' = 1994, and 10 = October.
LocalDate ldLater = ld.plusDays( 90 ) ;
```

Or use `Month` enum.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1994 , Month.OCTOBER , 20 ) ; 
LocalDate ldLater = ld.plusDays( 90 ) ;
```

Let java.time automatically localize for you.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.FULL ).withLocale( Locale.US ) ;
String output = ldLater.format( f ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).